# How can I get one column after a filter with DAX in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Lets say I have a `date` table which contains many fields. However I just want to get the week column from it, how can I do that?

I was able to apply the filter like this.

```
today = FILTER('date', 'date'[Date] = TODAY())
```

But here today has many fields, while I just want to return the week. Basically I would like the equivalent of something like this.

```
todays_week = GET_COLUMN(FILTER('date', 'date'[Date] = TODAY()), 'Week')
```

Comment: Whats wrong if you simplly use "week = date[week]"?

Comment: I only want to get the week, which corresponds to today's week. That is what that filter is for.

Answer (score 1):

We can calculate this like that:

```
todays_week = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('date'[week]), 'date'[Date] = TODAY())
```